# “minus-sign” into this regular expression. How?

Tags: java, regex

Consider:

```
String str = "XYhaku(ABH1235-123548)";
```

From the above string, I need only "ABH1235-123548" and so far I created a regular expression:

```
Pattern.compile("ABH\\d+")
```

But it returns false. So what the correct regular expression for it?

Comment: Try `Pattern.compile("ABH[\\d-]+")`. Note that `\d` does not include `-`

Answer (score 1):

`\d` only matches digits. To include other characters, use a  [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
Pattern.compile("ABH[\\d-]+")
```

Note that the `-` must be placed first or last in the character class, because otherwise it will be treated as a range indicator (`[A-Z]` matching every letter between `A` and `Z`, for example). Another way to avoid that would be to escape it, but that adds two more backslashes to your string...

Comment: I believe you can still escape (`\\-`) the range indicraator within a character class at any point.

Comment: That's right. It's a personal preference of mine not to add more backslashes to a regex when it can be avoided, especially in Java, but it's not an absolute requirement.

Comment: wont this get more than one `-` symbol? `ABH\d+-\d+` would be enough right?

Comment: @AbdulHameed: For the string format shown in the single example, yes. We don't know how universal that is. Maybe some strings won't have dashes, maybe some will have more than two? My regex is less strict than it could be. That could be good or bad, we don't know.

Comment: yeah... i hope the OP adds more test cases

Answer (score 1):

I would just grab whatever is in the parenthesis:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((?<data>[A-Z\\d]+\\-\\d+)\\)");
```

Or, if you want to be even more open (any parenthesis):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((?<data>.+\\)\\)");
```

Then just nab it:

```
String s = /* some input */;
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) { //just find first
    String tag = m.group("data"); //ABH1235-123548
}
```